# VSC HTML css class autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

В microsoft visual studio code не работает автоподстновка css class в html.
Устанавливал HTML CSS Class Completion - не работает. Делал Ctrl+Shift+P and then typing "Cache CSS class definitions" - не работает.
Устанавливал HTML Class Suggestions - не работает.
Версия VSC 1.11.1
Что нужно сделать ? В чём прикол ? Что не так ?